# View bar graphic with holoviews

Tags: python-3.x, holoviews

I am trying to view a bar graph by using holoviews.
Simply I worote this code below.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

data = [('one',8),('two', 10), ('three', 16), ('four', 8), ('five', 4), 
('six', 1)]
bars = hv.Bars(data, hv.Dimension('Car occupants'), 'Count')

print(bars)
```

On jupyter notebook it works. Does holoviews work only with jupyter notebook?
If not, what should I do to view it on shell?

Answer (score 2):

HoloViews supports Jupyter Notebooks and uses them extensively for its examples, because the notebook format allows output to be shown alongside the code that produced it.  But if what you want to work with the output directly, you can e.g. render it to an HTML file:

```
import numpy as np, holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

data = [('one',8),('two', 10), ('three', 16), ('four', 8), ('five', 4), ('six', 1)]
bars = hv.Bars(data, hv.Dimension('Car occupants'), 'Count')

renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
renderer.save(bars, 'output')
```

You can then load `output.html` into your web browser.  See [Plots and Renderers](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plots_and_Renderers.html) and [Deploying Bokeh Apps](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Deploying_Bokeh_Apps.html) for more options, including rendering to PNG or running live standalone servers.

Comment: thank you  James. I wonder does it work in the same way, if I add  a select field (kdims) in the graph?

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what you mean, but this approach should work for *any* holoviews object that doesn't need to communicate with a live Python server (because no such server will be around any more by the time the HTML file is used).  So you can't use DynamicMap or anything based on it (datashade, decimate, and a few other operations), but any "static" (HTML-only) plot should work fine.